# Complex CSS Positioning for an Interactive Timeline - Float, or Absolute, or Both?

Tags: css, html, css-float, css-position, timeline

I'm creating an interactive timeline where each event is a list item with HTML5 data tags that set the start date and end date. (See below)

```
<ul>
    <li data-start="-4181" data-end="-3251">Adam</li>
    <li data-start="-4173" data-end="-4117">Cain</li>
    <li data-start="-4163" data-end="-4125">Abel</li>
    <li data-start="-4051" data-end="-3139">Seth</li>
    <li data-start="-3946" data-end="-3041">Enos</li>
</ul>
```

I'm getting jQuery to properly set the width of each event, and a margin-left from the beginning of the parent div as you can see below.

[image: Timeline]

Here's my real question... I'm currently using float:left on the list items, but the short ones, such as Cain and Abel, are floating against the list item for Adam, rather than jumping to a new line and positioning properly against the left. This makes sense, and should float against the neighboring element is there is space in the parent element - BUT, is there a way to use a combination of floating and absolute positioning to dynamically align these items?

The final timeline will have 800+ events, and I need them to nicely share the timeline space AND I don't want them to stack any taller than 10 events high.

Any help, or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using HTML5 canvas element for this?

Comment: good idea is to use canvas -eg:- http://everytimezone.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a lot of complex JavaScript to make this work correctly. You need to calculate where each previous box is, then have jquery place the next box in a position so that it won't conflict with any previous ones. Use `position:absolute` but have javascript calculate where it should go. Assign each li a `top` and `left` value using jquery based off where you calculated it to be placed. CSS float won't be able to do what you want, don't use it at all in this case.

Comment: That's what I feared. Any thoughts on how to do this? What about saving each box position in an array and testing against that array before setting the top and left positioning?

Comment: Maybe have a `lines` array where you sort the added blocks by what line you placed them on. Then have the system test `lines[0]` first, and if there is not space there then go on to the next line. That will cause you to use the least number of lines possible. To test for available space on a line just check every box already on that line to see if they overlap with the one you are trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need more than one of them to appear on the same line, you may not need to float them. And unless the bars should overlap with one another or with some other content, you may not need CSS positioning.

It sounds like you just need to allow the li tags to be unfloated block-level elements, with a margin set for each one as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your you text in a `span` or `p` or anything you like and then apply any `javascript` to them and give the `li` full width of your space. This won't need `floating` or `absolute positioning`.